# Making a request using requests.get through tor proxies but the code is not responding

Tags: python, python-requests, tor

I want to make multiple GET requests using Tor to a webpage. I want to use a different ipaddress for each request,So i write the small program

```
from stem import Signal
from stem.control import Controller
import requests

def change_ip():
    with Controller.from_port(port=9051) as contr:
        contr.authenticate(password='abhishek')
        contr.signal(Signal.NEWNYM)


session=requests.session()

session.proxies={}

session.proxies['http']='socks5://127.0.0.1:9051'
session.proxies['https']='socks5://127.0.0.1:9051'

for i in range(5):
    r=session.get('http://httpbin.org/ip')
    print(r.text)
    change_ip()
```

Using this, i made multiple requests but this program not show any output and it stuck like i have shown in this image [this is the screenshot of terminal where i run this program and it stucked](https://i.stack.imgur.com/41I1S.png)

but when i remove the session.proxies area of code, the code is running and shows the output but it makes no sense to me because i want to change ip address after each request.

Comment: Hi, welcome to SO. Can you please elaborate on what do you mean by its not responding or showing an error? How are you trying to run it? please update the question with a detailed explanation. Thanks.

Comment: I edited the question, please help how to solve this

Comment: Tor runs proxy on port `9050`, not `9051`. Port `9051` is used only to control/change Tor

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Tor runs proxy on port `9050`, not `9051`. Port `9051` is used only to control/change Tor.

---

I also need few seconds after sending singnal to get new IP.

And it works better when I don't use one session for all urls but normal requests

```
requests.get(..., proxies=proxies)
```

With one session it sometimes gives the same IP for https://httpbin.org/ip and https://api.ipify.org but not for https://icanhazip.com .

It works correctly if I create new session in every loop.

---

Version without session

```
from stem import Signal
from stem.control import Controller
import requests
import time

def change_ip():
    with Controller.from_port(port=9051) as control:
        control.authenticate(password='password')
        control.signal(Signal.NEWNYM)

proxies = {
    'http':  'socks5://127.0.0.1:9050',
    'https': 'socks5://127.0.0.1:9050',
}    

for i in range(5):

    r = requests.get('https://httpbin.org/ip', proxies=proxies)
    print(r.json()['origin'])
    
    r = requests.get('https://api.ipify.org', proxies=proxies)
    print(r.text)

    r = requests.get('https://icanhazip.com', proxies=proxies)
    print(r.text)

    change_ip()
    time.sleep(5)
```

---

Version with session - new session in every loop

```
from stem import Signal
from stem.control import Controller
import requests
import time

def change_ip():
    with Controller.from_port(port=9051) as control:
        control.authenticate(password='password')
        control.signal(Signal.NEWNYM)

for i in range(5):

    session = requests.Session()
    
    session.proxies = {
        'http':  'socks5://127.0.0.1:9050',
        'https': 'socks5://127.0.0.1:9050',
    }    
    
    r = session.get('https://httpbin.org/ip')
    print(r.json()['origin'])

    r = session.get('https://api.ipify.org')
    print(r.text)

    r = session.get('https://icanhazip.com')
    print(r.text)

    change_ip()
    time.sleep(5)
```

Comment: i have run this code and face an error =>requests.exceptions.ConnectionError: SOCKSHTTPSConnectionPool(host='httpbin.org', port=443): Max retries exceeded with url: /ip (Caused by NewConnectionError('<urllib3.contrib.socks.SOCKSHTTPSConnection object at 0x7f5910c3b820>: Failed to establish a new connection: 0x01: General SOCKS server failure'))

Comment: do you have problem to connect with https://httpbin.org/ip in browser ? Maybe only server has some problem at this moment. OR maybe you have to update `OpenSSL` to correctly work with SSL and HTTPS ? Do you have problem with other urls - https://api.ipify.org and https://icanhazip.com ?

Comment: yes https://httpbin.org/ip and https://api.ipify.org/ raise the same error but https://icanhazip.com/ this site raises this permission denied error => stem.connection.UnreadableCookieFile: Authentication failed: unable to read '/run/tor/control.authcookie' ([Errno 13] Permission denied: '/run/tor/control.authcookie')  but i did not apply any password on tor control port

Comment: do you have problem when you use `http://` instead of `https://` ? Did you use your password in `control.authenticate(password='password')` ? If  you don't have password on tor then did you try to run it without password ?

Comment: maybe it will run without `Permission denied: '/run/tor/control.authcookie'` if you run it as admin - `sudo python script.py` - but it is strange that it has problem to access it.

Comment: yes it works, when i ran the command with `sudo` but any solution for removing the `sudo` from command.

Comment: I don't remeber how I instelled it but I don't have to use `sudo`. Maybe if you install it in your folder as normal user. OR maybe you should set password in tor and use it to get access without `sudo`.